# How to get last value before 0 in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to grab last value before 0 in SQL Server 2012?

[image]

Comment: How do you define "last"? Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you find the minimum date where `RunningTotal` is 0. Then you find the non zero value that is earlier than date

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   yourtable t
WHERE  t.RunningTotal  <> 0
AND    t.AccountingDate < (SELECT MIN(AccountingDate) FROM yourtable WHERE RunningTotal = 0)
ORDER BY t.AccountingDate DESC
```